# How to print a particular NR with awk

Tags: awk

I need to print out a particular record, which is the 3d from the tail, that is NR == total NR-2. I've been trying to do that for almost an hour and still can't get it work, so this is what I have:

```
cat myfile | grep mystring | awk 'END {NR == $(NR-2); print $0}'
```

This gives me the last NR, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` processes each line and just throws it out when it's done, you have to save it manually [N.B. Your `NR == $(NR-2)` checks whether the number of rows is equal to the (number of rows - 2)th field in the last row]. Easiest would be to store them all, but that's not very memory efficient so we can store just the last three we've seen. Actually the easiest would be to use `head` and `tail`:

```
grep mystring myfile | tail -n3 | head -n1
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk '/mystring/{three = two; two = one; one = $0} END{print three}' myfile
```

Comment: thank you, how's that possible? I mean, is three|two|one variables?

Comment: @user1413424 Yes, `three`, `two`, and `one` are variables. In awk, any bare word is a variable. (`$x` indicates a positional variable, i.e. the `x`th field, and `x` can even be a variable!)

Comment: yes, I understand, I just didn't know these "three" "two" "one" are reserved vars that actually refer to NR. Am I right?

Comment: No, they're not reserved, they're just the variables I picked for ease of remembering which line we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities.

you can use the command [tac](http://man.cx/tac) (instead cat) to reverse the file (from tail to head) and print the 3rd

or use a buffer to put in memory the last x results

Comment: `rev` reverses characters within a line, you're looking for `tac`.